# Collision detection on rotated image in javascript

Tags: html, image, math, canvas, rotation

I have created a js function, that should rotate a image for a collision detection, but the function don't works correct, when the rotation gets over π*1.5 (Pi), will the image crops.

```
function rotateImage(image , rotation)
{

    // Creates a canvas
    var rotatedImage = document.createElement( "canvas" ) . getContext( "2d" ),

    // Setting a bounding box size
    boundingWidth = Math . abs( image . height * Math . cos( rotation ) + image . width * Math . sin( rotation ) ),
    boundingHeight = Math . abs( image . height * Math . sin( rotation ) + image . width * Math . cos( rotation ) );

    // Changing canvas size
    rotatedImage . canvas.width = boundingWidth;
    rotatedImage . canvas.height = boundingHeight;

    // Translating canvas
    rotatedImage . translate( boundingWidth/2 , boundingHeight/2 );

    // Rotate canvas
    rotatedImage . rotate( rotation );

    // Un-translating canvas
    rotatedImage . translate( -boundingWidth/2 , -boundingHeight/2 );

    // Draws image
    rotatedImage . drawImage( image , 0 , 0 );

    // Returns canvas
    return rotatedImage . canvas;

}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, if rotation is all you need why not use CSS transforms?

Comment: If you have access to an html canvas, you have access to css animations that will rotate images for you.

Answer (score 3):

**[Edited: OP clarified they want collision detection]**

Ohhh...you want the bounding box of a rotated rectangle to use in collision detection.

You don't need to use canvas rotation for that, just use trigonometry!

```
// where w = rectangle width (sprite width)
// where h = rectangle height (sprite height)
// where a = angle of rotation in degrees
// calculate the bounding box of the rectangle at the given rotation

function BoundingBoxDimensions(w,h,a){
  var rads=a*Math.PI/180;
  var c = Math.abs(Math.cos(rads));
  var s = Math.abs(Math.sin(rads));
  return({  width: h * s + w * c,  height: h * c + w * s });
}
```

Regarding your code above,  if your Math.sin(rotation) or Math.cos(rotation) go negative, you'll want to take their absolute values before using them in your BB calculation.  That's why your calculation goes crazy at PI * 1.5.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i know how i can draw rotated images, but i needs a function that return the rotated sprite to find the collision of the new width and height.

Comment: Collision detection(!?)...that would have been useful info to put in your question :p   OK, see my edited answer to get your rotated bounding box.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and sorry for i dont write anything about collision detection, i have edited the question.

Comment: @markE, can you please add the XY axis points in parameter and the return value? Thanks